# Set order of y axis in python with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot simple arrays with values a,b,c and d. I want to plot these arrays in alphabetical order. For example I added a plot of the fifth row in the dataframe given below, the y-value starts at 'a' (good) and then the next y-value is 'c' (wrong), I want to have 'b' at that place. In short; the y values should be in alphabetical order without losing the x value order.

[image]

The head of the dataset is given. It is very basic.

[image]

And the (very basic) code
`bins = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; plt.plot((X_sax.iloc[4,:])); plt.yticks(bins);`

Can Someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you can just enclose your y axis list in sorted(), but if you post your code we can know for sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Comment: @B.Bogart done!

Answer (score 1):

I would map the y axis to values and then name the axis as @Yogesh suggested.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
X_sax = list('accbcbbbbcb')

datamap = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3, 'd':4}
X_sax = list(map(lambda x: datamap[x], X_sax))
           
plt.plot((X_sax))
plt.yticks([1,3,2,4], bins)
```

gives:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 1):

Next code uses [NumPy](https://numpy.org/)-only functions for very fast processing of data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd, numpy as np
# ----- Input -----
bins = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
X_sax = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array([list('accbcbbbbcb')]))
print(X_sax)
# ----- Show ------
v = X_sax.values[0, :] # Choose which row to show
b = np.sort(bins)
v = np.searchsorted(b, v)
plt.plot(v)
plt.yticks(np.arange(b.size), b)
plt.show()
```

You may also [try code above online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64647174#main.py)

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
0  a  c  c  b  c  b  b  b  b  c  b
```

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(len_of_y_ticks), y_order)
```

Eg:

```
x = np.arange(0, 11)
y = 'a c c b c b b b b c b'.split()
y_order = sorted(set(y))
len_of_y_ticks = len(set(y))
y = list(map(lambda x: ord(x)-97, y))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks(np.arange(4), y_order)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. Now i get the same output as graph above, only b and c are swapped.
But i want that the graph handles the data also in alphabetical order. Not only changing the ticks. The value 'c' should be considered higher than 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case add y = list(map(lambda x: ord(x)-97, y)) before plt.plot(x, y). I have edited the main code, now hopefully it satisfies you.